# Websphere deployment removes uri-groups from plugin-cfg.xml

Tags: jenkins-plugins, websphere-8

Im new to websphere and have a  requirement to deploy 3 EAR application in Websphere 8 Cluster environment using jenkin's Websphere deploy plugin. The deployment works fine, but after deployment the plug-in.cfg.xml is modified and uri-groups settings and virtual hosts settings is removed for 2 apps. Websever is ibm http server. The plugin-cfg.xml is located under the websphere/Plugins/config/webserver/ folder. Can anyone please help with this and how the plugin-cfg.xml is populated.

Comment: it sounds like your modules are not mapped to the webserver. You can see before/aftter in the console: All Applications > my-app > Manage Modules

Comment: Thank you. It worked after all targets in manage-module were added in target field of websphere deployer plugin. But certain entries from virtual host group and uri group is missing. Can you please share the details of how these tags in plugin cfg.xml is populated